# Python Windows IDLE

Tags: python, idle

Когда я использую Windows 7 без прав администратора я могу открыть IDLE Python,а когда с правами администратора,то появляется ошибка Can't find a default python.Что мне нужно сделать,чтобы запустить IDLE Python с правами администратора?

Comment: На моём компьютере есть два пользователя:один с правами администратора,другой без них.

Comment: Наверно можно переустановить питон от администратора, не забыть в инсталлере "установить для всех пользователей" и все должно быть норм.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно не уверен, но попробуй проверить наличие строки в переменных средах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]